# Bijection between $\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)$ and $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\sqcup \mathsf{Sh}(p-1, q+1)$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p$ and $q$ be two positive integers. Define $$\mathsf{Sh}(p, q):=\{\sigma\in\mathsf{S}_{p+q}: \sigma(1)<\ldots<\sigma(p)\ \textrm{and}\ \sigma(p+1)<\ldots<\sigma(p+q)\},$$ where $\mathsf{S}_{p+q}$ is the set of permutations of the first $p+q$ integers, i.e, bijections of $\{1, \ldots, p+q\}$. An element of $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)$ is called a $(p, q)$-shuffle.

It can be seen that $$\#\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)=\binom{p+q}{p}.$$

In particular, we see that $$\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)=\#\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)+\#\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q-1),$$ and therefore $$\#\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\quad \textrm{and}\quad \mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\sqcup \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q-1)$$ 
are in bijection. How to construct an explicit bijection between those sets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, you have a wrong identity. Notice that $Sh(3+1,2)=\binom{6}{4}=15,Sh(3,2)=\binom{5}{3}=10$ and $Sh(2,3)=\binom{5}{2}=10$ but $15\neq 10+10.$
I am going to make the assumption that you wanted to use Pascal's recursion, in which case the correct identity is $$|Sh(p,q+1)|=|Sh(p,q)|+|Sh(p-1,q+1)|.$$

In order to prove the later, let $\sigma \in Sh(p,q+1),$ then there are $2$ options: 
$\bullet $ $\sigma ^{-1}(p+q+1)<=p$:   if you remove $p+q+1$ you end up with a permutation in  $Sh(p\color{red}{-1},q+1).$ 
$\bullet$ $\sigma ^{-1}(p+q+1)>p$:if you remove $p+q+1$ you end up with a permutation in $Sh(p,q+1\color{red}{-1})=Sh(p,q).$
It should be clear the bijection from here.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Thanks for your answer =)

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down the details so I'm going to share just in case someone else needs it someday.

The first thing to be noticed is that $\sigma^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1, p+2\}$, hence:

$$\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)=\{\sigma\in \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q): \sigma(1)=1\}\sqcup \{\sigma\in\mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q): \sigma(p+2)=1\}.$$
This allows us to define the bijection easily setting:

$$\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\\ \sigma\longmapsto \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}1 & 2& \ldots & p+2 &  \ldots &p+q+1\\ 1 &\sigma(1)+1 & \ldots &\sigma(p+1)+1 & \ldots & \sigma(p+q)+1 \end{array}\right)$$
and

$$ \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q-1)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(p+1, q)\\ \sigma\longmapsto \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}1 & \ldots &p+1 & p+2 & p+3& \ldots & p+q+1\\ \sigma(1)+1 & \ldots & \sigma(p+1)+1 & 1 & \sigma(p+2)+1 & \ldots &\sigma(p+q)+1  \end{array}\right).$$ The inverse should be clear from the definitions.